# Spring actuator 'health' metrics doesn't respond if kafka is down

Tags: spring, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

`HealthEndpoint.invoke` that contains all the 'health' metrics (db, diskspace, ...) doesn't response if Kafka is down. Thus, I can't get any health metrics in such case.
How can I get other health metrics status in such case? Or some other approach to distinguish live from failed components?

Answer (score 1):

Timeout for kafka health indicator could be set this way:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.healthTimeout: 5
```